# JavaScript mutating concat

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a reference to an array `a1`. I have an array of extra values `a2`. I want to concatenate all the values of `a2` onto `a1`, *mutating the original array*.

Using `concat()` does not work, because it is non-mutating. For example:

```
var a0 = [1,2,3];
var a1 = a0;
var a2 = [4,5,6];
a1 = a1.concat(a2);
console.log(a1); // [1,2,3,4,5,6] YAY
console.log(a0); // [1,2,3]       BOO
```

Is there a better way to do this other than something like:

```
for (var i=0; i<a2.length; ++i) a1.push(a2[i]);
```

Comment: Thanks +Barmar. I was sure there had to be a duplicate, and I did search for a while, but somehow failed to find it.

Answer (score 0):

The mutating [`push()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) accepts more than one argument. By using the [`apply()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) you can pass all the values from `a2` as parameters to `push()`:

```
// Mutate a1 to have all the values of a2 added
a1.push.apply(a1, a2);
```

In action:

```
var a0 = [1,2,3];
var a1 = a0;
var a2 = [4,5,6];
a1.push.apply(a1, a2);
console.log(a1); // [1,2,3,4,5,6] YAY
console.log(a0); // [1,2,3,4,5,6] YAY!!
```